What to do when answers to a question need maintenance?
I've spotted a question which answers seem to need update following recent results, e.g. this.
How to best deal with that?

I would say we have a few options.

Leave a comment on the accepted answer with the updated information and ask the author to add the info.
Edit the answer with the new info (for example, I've been trying to do this on a previous answer I supplied)
Add a new answer with the updated information.
Ask a new question which has a reference to the old question. The new question could say something like "how do the results of paper X change the answers to question Y here on Crypto.SE". Then either edit question Y to include a link to the new question or add a comment on question Y to the new question.


Did 1 and 4, it worked!
